# angularjs throws 'undefined' error if cookie name contains hyphen (dash) in it

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $cookies to read cookies. However one of my cookies has a hyphen / dash inbetween. When I tried to do that, angularjs throws 'undefined' error eventhough the cookie exists. However this is not happening for cookie names without hyphen / dash in it.

For. ex,

```
$cookies.Auth-PD-ID
```

throws an error as below

**'PD' is undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hyphen is the minus operator, the Javascript interpreter thinks you're trying to do subtraction.  When the property name contains special characters, you need to wrap it in quotes and access it like this:

```
$cookies["Auth-PD-ID"]
```